# java insert null date in mysql with update query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, windowbuilder

I'm working on java app (GUI, JDBC, MySQL) and I have problem which I can't solve.

When I insert data into MySQL DB (there are this data type String, INT, Date), there isn't problem if some fields are empty. That empty fields gets Null into DB. But, when I want to update some row, all date field have to be filled or it is error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'rociste_datum' at row 1
```

`rociste_datum` is first date column in DB

There are parts of the code:

Code for insert method

```
    public void insertPredmetDB(String prezime, String ime, int nasBroj, Date datumRocista) {
        if (datumRocista == null || datumRocista.equals("")) {
            datumRocistaDB = null;
        } else {
            String datumRocistaSt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(datumRocista);
            datumRocistaDB = java.sql.Date.valueOf(datumRocistaSt);
        }
```

Code for update method

```
public void updatePredmetDB(int idNovo, String novoPrezime, String novoIme, int noviNasBroj, Date noviRocisteDatum) {
    if (noviRocisteDatum == null || noviRocisteDatum.equals("")) {
        noviRocisteDatumDB = null;
    } else {
        String datumRocistaSt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(noviRocisteDatum);
        noviRocisteDatumDB = java.sql.Date.valueOf(datumRocistaSt);
    }
    String izmena = "UPDATE predmeti SET prezime='" + novoPrezime + "', ime='" + novoIme + "', nas_broj='" + noviNasBroj + "', rociste_datum='" + noviRocisteDatumDB + "'where id='" + idNovo + "'";

    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(izmena);

        ps.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For all this dates there are if else statements, and this objects are passing through controller with singleton pattern. I think that it is not necessary to put that code here because there are no errors, and everything works fine, except this dates.

I think that there is a problem with date conversion. Could you give me any help?

Comment: Don't try and glue variables into your SQL. Use [statement parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) instead. See https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Especially since you are already using a `PreparedStatement`,  consider using its `?` placeholders system. As it is, you are trying to update your date  column with the value `'null'` , which is obviously not a valid string representation of a date.

Comment: Further skip `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, those classes are long outdated. Assuming you can use Java 8 or later and JDBC 4.2 or later, use `java.time.LocalDate` and `ps.setObject(4, yourLocalDate)`. I would expect it to work if `yourLocalDate` is `null` too. As an aside `datumRocista.equals("")` will never be true, a `Date` cannot be equal to a string.

Answer (score 4):

when you do string concatenation like

```
rociste_datum='" + noviRocisteDatumDB + "'
```

then you end up with

```
rociste_datum='null'
```

instead of

```
rociste_datum=null
```

no quotes this time. db is expecting a date or null not the string 'null'

Hence use placeholders before creating prepared statement and then set the params.

```
"UPDATE predmeti SET prezime=?, ime=?, nas_broj=?, rociste_datum=? where id=?";
```

Comment: I updated the code but it is still the same error com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'rociste_datum' at row 1    String izmena ="UPDATE predmeti SET prezime=?, ime=?, nas_broj=?, rociste_datum=? where id=?";  
  try {

   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(izmena);
   
   ps.setString(1, novoPrezime);
   ps.setString(2, novoIme);
   ps.setInt(3, noviNasBroj);
   ps.setDate(4, noviRocisteDatumDB);
   ps.setInt(5, idNovo);

   ps.execute();